# Original file name of precompiled header

Tags: c++, c, gcc, precompiled-headers

Is it possible to extract original filename (filepath) and compilation language from precompiled header? As I understand it's possible for Clang using `llvm-bcanalyzer` (LLVM bit code analyzer). So, could anybody help me with GCC?

Comment: A precompiled header most likely combines a lot (transcluded) .h files. What name exactly to do seek?

Comment: I tried to found the original header name which is the source for precompiled header. According to documentation you can create PHC using the follow command: gcc -x c-header **test.h** -o test.h.gch. In my case I would like to extract the path to **test.h**

Comment: Yes. Clang allows me to receive that information [Clang PHC Internal metadata] (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/PCHInternals.html#ast-file-contents).

Answer (score 2):

For clang you can easily extract original PCH filename just parsing preprocessor output.
In out example `header/header.h` is original header and `pch/pch.h.gch` is precompiled header.

For example the follow command: `clang -E -include pch/pch.h main.cpp` returns result where we can find original PCH filename:

```
…
# 1 "/Users/user/pch_example/header/header.h" 1
…
# 1 "main.cpp" 2
int main() {return 42;}
```

Unfortunately parsing preprocessor output doesn’t help us with GCC, even if you use it with `-fpch-preprocess` option. So the only one way I found is compiling PCH with enabled dependency-tracking flag like `-MD (or -MMD)`.

For example we can call the follow command: `gcc-6 -MMD -x c++-header header/header.h -o pch/pch.h.pch`. In this case GCC additionally generates dependency-file `pch/pch.h.d`, which contains path to the original PCH filename.